# How to solve this equation from a FOE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How do I solve this

$$5000 =  21t - 111.37e^\frac{-12t}{6.5625} + 1207.12$$

I am using the *image below as a guide* for **my own question (above)** but they mention to use math software to solve the equation but I have used Symbolab, Mathway and Photomath to solve and they wont work.

Have I done something wrong?

[image]

Comment: Essentially you have an equation
$$at+b\cdot e^{ct}=d$$
In general it's not possible to get a closed form for $t$.

Answer (score 1):

Working with whole numbers and making the problem more general, you need to fing the zero of function
$$f(t)=15 t-\frac{379}{5} e^{-\frac {32}{15} t}+\frac{11503}{10}-k$$ and, as @vitamin d showed using Wolfram Alpha, the only explicit solution is given by
$$t=\frac {10k-11503}{150}+\frac{15}{32}W\left(\frac{12128}{1125}\exp\Big[ -\frac{16 (10 k-11503)}{1125}\Big]\right)$$ where $W(t)$ is Lambert function.

For $k=5000$, the argument of Lambert function is extremely small  $(\sim 1.78 \times 10^{-237})$ and can be neglected. So, avery good approximation is
$$t \sim \frac{38497}{150} \sim 256.6466667$$ while the exact solution would be  the same !

Comment: Yeah I am asking about the equation written in Latex.Emphasize on "image below as a guide".